# Как достать first_name

Tags: reactjs, vk-mini-apps

**Нужно достать элемент first_name**
**Я обращаюсь к библиотеке VkBridge** - `bridge.send('VKWebAppGetUserInfo');`
[image: Полученные данные]

Как достать из объекта first_name и вывести в консоль?

Answer (score 1):

VKBridge возвращает [промис](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise), а для работы с ним лучше можно использовать конструкцию `.then().catch()`.
В итоге получится примерно следующее:

```
bridge.send('VKWebAppGetUserInfo')
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.first_name)
    // *назначение переменных*
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Нужно учитывать, что если назначать значение переменной в блоке then, то это значение появится в переменной **не сразу**. При использовании значения таких переменных нужно быть уверенным, что эти значения уже успели туда записаться. Для этого нужно делать проверки - "отличается ли текущее значение от дефолтного"